# Tell Browserify to expose module deps

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Is there any way to expose **internal dependencies** of module to global `require`?

I mean I've got `index.js` like this:

```js
var dep = require('./dep.js');
console.log(dep);
```

And I've added it to Browserify bundle thru it's API like this:

```js
var b = browserify();
b.add('path/to/module');
b.bundle().pipe(process.stdout);
```

So how can I get `require('./dep.js')` outside of result bundle file?

I'm talking about Node.js API of Browserify, not CLI.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I think I'm facing a similar issue. The bundle is a 'closed booked', and I've no idea how to get my other bundles to be able to see its internals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking but:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');

var b = browserify();
var deps = [];
b.add('path/to/module');
// pull array out of stream:
b.deps().on('data', function(data){deps.push(data);})
    .on('end',function(){
        deps.forEach(function(item)
        {
            //item.id will be the file name
            console.log(item);
        });
    } );
```

If you literally just want the require dependency, browserify uses module-deps internally which is on github [here](https://github.com/substack/module-deps) or on npm.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
// index.js
var dep = require('./dep.js');
console.log(dep);

//========================

// your browserify script
var b = browserify();
b.add('./path/to/index.js');

// expose the module to global require as 'deps'
b.require('./path/to/deps.js', { expose: 'deps' });

b.bundle().pipe(process.stdout);
```

this should make the `deps.js` module available outside the bundle as `deps`

so doing this in the developer tools console will give you access to the module

```
require('deps'); // will require the deps.js module
```